# HTML5 getUserStream live broadcasting

Tags: javascript, flash, html, video-streaming, rtmp

Good afternoon.
I need to write a web application for videoconferencing, but I do not want to use flash or desktop applications.
Course for listeners the client may be a flash player, but on my side I want to have html5/js page to capture video / audio stream.

I found WebRTC API getUserMedia and peerConnection as a good starting point, but I need to broadcast video to hundreds of users, which means I need a server to restriminga. Something on the similarity of RED5 or Wowza, but to use them I need to encode the video stream and pack. But how? is there a description of the stream returned getUserMedia? What container should I use? is there any ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The getUserMedia API is not supported by any browser out there yet, although some have it available in experimental builds. For this reason you won't be able to use it yet.

Opera have an example of using it in [Playing with HTML5 video & getUserMedia support](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/playing-with-html5-video-and-getusermedia-support/).

The peerConnection API is also as of yet unsupported (and incomplete!).

Comment: I want to start using getUserMedia now, because in the next 3-4 months this api will be supported by all major browsers.

By the way Chrome supports getUserMedia from 18 version. of peerConnection - yes, I realized that for my purposes better to use sockets

Comment: in any case the main issue in the coding blob, with no loss of synchronization of audio and video streams.

Comment: The API is now more widely supported. Is this more possible now?